# Restate a join query as correlated subquery in the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

As a practice assignment, I'm looking to to rewrite a join as a subquery in the select clause. I understand that a subquery in the select statement must return a single value and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to rewrite this in a way that will make sense.

Here's the original join statement:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceLineItemAmount
FROM Invoices JOIN InvoiceLineItems
  ON Invoices.InvoiceID = Invoicelineitems.InvoiceID
WHERE VendorID = 122
ORDER BY InvoiceDate
```

Any tips or assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are the table definitions? We need to guess which columns belong to which tables at the moment and the cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

My tip is to have the InvoiceLineItems in your main query and Invoices in your subquery.  That will increase the likelihood of having your subquery returning exactly one row.

Comment: +1 Assuming the relationship is 1 invoice to many line items this would work. The answers with `FROM Invoices` wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `ON` clause you just place the condition in the `WHERE` clause of the subquery.

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate,
       (SELECT InvoiceLineItemAmount
        FROM InvoiceLineItems
        WHERE Invoices.InvoiceID = Invoicelineitems.InvoiceID)
          AS InvoiceLineItemAmount
FROM Invoices
WHERE VendorID = 122
ORDER BY InvoiceDate
```

If your subquery is returning more than one value, then you have a few options.

You can grab the `TOP 1`

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate,
       (SELECT TOP 1 InvoiceLineItemAmount
        FROM InvoiceLineItems
        WHERE Invoices.InvoiceID = Invoicelineitems.InvoiceID)
          AS InvoiceLineItemAmount
FROM Invoices
WHERE VendorID = 122
ORDER BY InvoiceDate
```

You can use an aggregate function

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate,
       (SELECT MAX(InvoiceLineItemAmount)
        FROM InvoiceLineItems
        WHERE Invoices.InvoiceID = Invoicelineitems.InvoiceID)
          AS InvoiceLineItemAmount
FROM Invoices
WHERE VendorID = 122
ORDER BY InvoiceDate
```

Or you can concatenate the results using XML

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate,
       STUFF((
           SELECT ', ' + LTRIM(InvoiceLineItemAmount)
           FROM InvoiceLineItems
           WHERE Invoices.InvoiceID = Invoicelineitems.InvoiceID
           FOR XML PATH('')),
           1, 2, '') AS InvoiceLineItemAmount
FROM Invoices
WHERE VendorID = 122
ORDER BY InvoiceDate
```

Or, for @MartinSmith, you can reverse the relation and hang off of InvoiceLineItems instead.  Without knowing your schema constraints you might run into the same `returns more than one value` issue, though.

```
SELECT (SELECT InvoiceNumber
        FROM InvoiceLineItems
        WHERE Invoices.InvoiceID = Invoicelineitems.InvoiceID)
            AS InvoiceNumber,
       (SELECT InvoiceDate
        FROM InvoiceLineItems
        WHERE Invoices.InvoiceID = Invoicelineitems.InvoiceID)
            AS InvoiceDate
       InvoiceLineItemAmount
FROM InvoiceLineItems
WHERE VendorID = 122
ORDER BY InvoiceDate
```

In the end it all depends on what your requirements are.

Comment: Lots of options but none of them have `FROM InvoiceLineItems` as the main query and `FROM Invoices` as the correlated sub query. With that way around assuming `InvoiceID` is the PK of `Invoices` and there is a foreign key preventing orphaned line items there can only  be exactly one matching row.

Comment: +1 I think we can make an educated guess that the `Invoices` table is unlikely to have more than one row with the same `InvoiceID`

Comment: I think that's a pretty good assumption, however, I have seen crazier things out there in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

If in subquery more than one row, then you need [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) clause

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, 
 (
  SELECT InvoiceLineItemAmount
  FROM InvoiceLineItems
  WHERE Invoices.InvoiceID = Invoicelineitems.InvoiceID
  ) AS InvoiceLineItemAmount 
FROM Invoices
WHERE VendorID = 122
ORDER BY InvoiceDate
```

Comment: Want to take another look at what you wrote?  Pay particular attention to what you have after the word "join".